# display comment form for specific post id

Tags: themes, comments, templates

I have three pages, and I want them all to display the comments form from a post with id=343. What code would I use within the pages to make that happen?

Here is what I've tried:

```
<?php
$id=343; // sample, I get the latest post id of a particular category
comments_template();
?>
```

But that doesn't work, it just shows the blank comment form from the page. Any thoughts / suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use `get_comments()` and pass the post ID as parameter:

```
$comments = get_comments(
    array (
        'post_id' => 343
    ) 
);

foreach ( $comments as $comment )
{
    // Just to give you an idea of the available data.
    // You will probably do something better with it. :)
    var_export( $comment );
}
```

Related: Bug [#20572](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20572) (`$post_id` not passed to `comment_open()` from `comment_form()`) was fixed just two days ago.

Answer (score -2):

use this if you want to show comment on a specific post `is_single('1')`

Comment: This is not what I'm trying to do. Lets say I have three pages, and I want them all to display the comments form from post (id=343). What code would I use within the pages to make that happen?

Comment: you can do this by giving or operator like this
`if(is_single(121) || is_single(5))`